# Add a border to `:LspInfo` window in Neovim

Tags: neovim, highlight, lsp

I use a transparent colorscheme for my Neovim. Due to the transparency, the `:LspInfo` window is difficult to distinguish from the background. Can I add a border around the window?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `require('lspconfig.ui.windows').default_options.border = 'single'` works